# Passing variable from foreach loop into context menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, contextmenu

Note: I am not asking how to fix my code because I haven't written a large part of it yet. I am asking how I would do something like what I describe below (ie attach the hyperlink that is generated by the foreach loop to the contextitem instead of just the User's name). Or a clearer way of stating it I suppose is I want the context-menu to know which User the User is right-clicking.

Hi so basically what I am trying to do is I have a list of users and on my webpage I want to print a list of usernames which, when right-clicked, a context-menu pops up with options such as "send friend request," or "Message user," and when the user clicks on one of these options, let's say the "Message user" option, the user is sent to another page with the clicked on user's ID in the URL as a query string.

This is what I have so far: a code snippet that generates a list of hyperlinks that when clicked on sends the user to the next page with the clicked-on User's ID in the URL

```html
<ul>
 <%foreach(UserCredential u in Global.Users) %>
 <%{ %>
  <li><a href="<%= "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + u.UserID.ToString() %>"><%= u.Name %></a></li>
 <%} %>
<ul />
```

And this is the code for the context-menu

```html
<div style="display:none; "   id="contextMenu">
        <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 

            style="border: thin solid #808080; cursor: default;" width="100px" 

            bgcolor="White">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <div  class="ContextItem">Message User</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                <div  class="ContextItem">Friend User</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <div  class="ContextItem">Delete</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
```

Basically I want to move the "a href="<%= "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + u.UserID.ToString() %>"" from the loop to where the user clicks on the ContextItem.

Here is what I have now:

```
function ShowMenu(control, e, id) {
        var posx = e.clientX + window.pageXOffset + 'px'; //Left Position of Mouse Pointer
        var posy = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset + 'px'; //Top Position of Mouse Pointer
        document.getElementById(control).style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(control).style.left = posx;
        document.getElementById(control).style.top = posy;

        a.style.position = 'absolute';
        a.style.display = 'inline';
        a.style.left = posx;
        a.style.top = posy;
        var jqContext = '#' + id;

        var view = document.getElementById("viewId");
        view.href = "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id;
    }
```

And this is my foreach loop:

```
<%foreach(UserCredential u in Global.Users) %>
        <%{ %>
            <li onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');" onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');" oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu', event, <%= u.UserID.ToString() %>);"><%= u.Name %></li>
        <%} %>
```

Here is my entire code. If anyone can figure out what's wrong with it please tell me.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProfilePicTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProfilePicTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function ShowMenu(control, e, id) {
   var posx = e.clientX + window.pageXOffset + 'px'; //Left Position of Mouse Pointer
   var posy = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset + 'px'; //Top Position of Mouse Pointer
   document.getElementById(control).style.position = 'absolute';
   document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById(control).style.left = posx;
   document.getElementById(control).style.top = posy;

   a.style.position = 'absolute';
   a.style.display = 'inline';
   a.style.left = posx;
   a.style.top = posy;
   var jqContext = '#' + id;

   var view = document.getElementById("viewId");
   view.href = "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id;
  }
  function HideMenu(control) {

   document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'none';
  }
       
 </script>
</head>
<body onclick="HideMenu('contextMenu');" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <ul>
   <%foreach(UserCredential u in Global.Users) %>
   <%{ %>
    <li onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');" onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');" oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu', event, 3);"><%= u.Name %></li>
   <%} %>
  </ul>
    </div>


  <br />
    <br />
    <div style="display:none; "   id="contextMenu">
        <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
            style="border: thin solid #808080; cursor: default;" width="100px" 
            bgcolor="White">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <a href="#" id="viewId">Send a Friend Request</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                  <a href="#"  id="editId">Message</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code-behind is empty:

Comment: Can you include the code of that shows context menu and event that is registered?

Comment: Well I'm not asking about how to fix my code because I haven't wrote it yet. I just want to know HOW I would do this (ie how I would attach the hyperlink to the ContextItem rather than just the User's name).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me know if this meets your expectation

```js
function ShowMenu(control, e, id) {
            var posx = e.clientX + 'px';
            var posy = e.clientY + 'px';
   var a = document.getElementById(control); 
   
            a.style.position = 'absolute';
            a.style.display = 'inline';
            a.style.left = posx;
            a.style.top = posy;
            var jqContext = '#' + control;
            
   var view = document.getElementById("viewId"); 
   view.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + id; //Construct your URL based on parameter
   
        }
        function HideMenu(control) {
            document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

```css
.ContextItem
        {
            background-color:White;
            color:Black;
            font-weight:normal;
            
            }
        .ContextItem:hover
        {
            background-color:#0066FF;
            color:White;
            font-weight:bold;
            
        }
       .detailItem
       {
           background:transparant;
           
       }
       .detailItem:hover
       {
           background-color:#FEE378;
           border: 1px outset #222222;
           font-weight:bold;
           cursor:default;
       }
```

```html
<body onclick="HideMenu('contextMenu');" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <div  onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
          onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
        oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event,1);"
         class="detailItem">
    User 1
        </div>
         <div  onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
          onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
        oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event,2);"
         class="detailItem">
     User 2
        </div>
       <div  onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
          onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
        oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event,3);"
         class="detailItem">
    User 3
        </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="display:none; "   id="contextMenu">
        <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
            style="border: thin solid #808080; cursor: default;" width="100px" 
            bgcolor="White">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <a href="#" id="viewId"> View</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                  <a href="#"  id="editId">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So I would replace the user 1,2,3 with my foreach loop?

Comment: Yes. I hard coded the users link. You may replace that logic with foreach loop.

Comment: I am getting "oncontextmenu is not a valid attribute of element div/li".

Comment: I added the function you recommended to my post. This function just sends me to the URL that I'm already on, just adding a "#" to the end of the URL. Perhaps this is related to the oncontextmenu is not valid problem I am getting?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/JS? I have updated my working code and here is another example http://www.htmlnest.com/html/div/event/oncontextmenu

Comment: I verified, it's working in both HTML 4.01 and HTML 5

Comment: Yeah I posted my HTML/JS above. Did you verify MY HTML/JS, because maybe I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Can you try removing 3 parameter into showMenu method once? Just to debug if context menu is working.

Comment: The context menu is working and the showMenu function is being called, just for whatever reason the showMenu function doesn't direct me anywhere. The view.href = "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id; doesn't seem to be functioning as a hyperlink.

Comment: view.href = "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id; may not work..You need specify the URL some thing like this  "~/ <folder name if any>/Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id

Comment: No the link itself doesn't seem to be working AT ALL, like it doesn't even link to a "Page Not Found" page, it does absolutely nothing. I tried both "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id and "~/Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id, both of them just changed the url from http://localhost:15626/MacTest/ProfilePicTest.aspx to http://localhost:15626/MacTest/ProfilePicTest.aspx#

Comment: Changed it to view.href = "google.com/"; but still nothing happens. Right now I assume the problem is something very little that I am overlooking, so I posted my entire code above. Tell me if you see anything wrong.

Comment: The only issue I see from your code is   view.href = "Chat.aspx?RecID=" + id; can you try replacing the exact path instead. some thing like this http://localhost:15626/<folder>/Chat.aspx

Comment: Can you post the text that you see when you mouse over the either "View" or "Edit" button? you should be able to see the text on the left bottom corner of the browser which should be a URL

Comment: When I hover my mouse over the "View" or "Edit" button the URL that is shown at the bottom left corner of my browser is localhost:15626/MacTest/ProfilePicTest.aspx#, regardless of whether I put "Chat.aspx?RecID=", "~/Chat.aspx?RecID=" , "google.com/", or anything else.

Comment: Were you able to run my sample code putting it in a HTML file? No external reference is required. try once.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. I honestly have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: Okay I recopied and pasted everything I could from your code and it works now, so I guess I must have added or missed something that threw it off. Thank you.